# Why do I get the error "configure: error: Cannot find glib: Is glib-config in path?"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, installation

I tried `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev` and got

> libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.

And I still get the error

```
configure: error: Cannot find glib: Is glib-config in path?
```

I am trying to install Netdude. I am getting this problem when trying to install libnetdude.

Answer (score 0):

`glib-config` is from glib 1.x, not glib 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. glib 1.x is obsolete? Would you please tell if there is a way to install Netdude?

Comment: Have you tried using something modern, like Wireshark?

Comment: No. I want to edit the pcap file. I want to combine multiple TCP packets into one TCP packet. That's why I am looking for pcap editors. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There's a command line program tcpsplice that can do what you're looking for.